# MySQL Select Records from 2 not-related Tables Ordering by Timestamp

Tags: mysql

I'd like to collect data from 2 different mysql tables ordering the result by a timestamp but without merging the columns of the 2 tables in a single row.

T_ONE(`one_id`,`one_someinfo`,`one_ts`)

T_TWO(`two_id`,`two_otherinfo`,`two_ts`)

Notice that the field two_otherinfo is not the same as one_someinfo, the only columns in common are id and timestamp.

The result should be a mix of the two tables ordered by the timestamp but each row, depending on the timestamp, should contain only the respective columns of the table.

For example, if the newest record comes from T_TWO that row should have the T_ONE `one_someinfo` column empty.

I just need to order the latest news from T_ONE and the latest messages posted on T_TWO so the tables are not related. I'd like to avoid using 2 queries and then merging and ordering the results by timestamp with PHP. Does anyone know a solution to this? Thanks in advance

---

This is the structure of the table

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `fromid` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `toteam` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `banned` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `replyid` int(15) default NULL,
  `cont` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE `stars` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `daynum` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `userid` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `vote` tinyint(2) NOT NULL default '3',
  `timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

INSERT INTO `posts` (`fromid`, `toteam`, `banned`, `replyid`, `cont`, `timestamp`) VALUES(5, 12, 0, 0, 'mess posted#1', 1222222220);
INSERT INTO `posts` (`fromid`, `toteam`, `banned`, `replyid`, `cont`, `timestamp`) VALUES(5, 12, 0, 0, 'mess posted#2', 1222222221);
INSERT INTO `posts` (`fromid`, `toteam`, `banned`, `replyid`, `cont`, `timestamp`) VALUES(5, 12, 0, 0, 'mess posted#3', 1222222223);

INSERT INTO `stars` (`daynum`, `userid`, `vote`, `timestamp`) VALUES(3, 160, 4, 1222222222);
INSERT INTO `stars` (`daynum`, `userid`, `vote`, `timestamp`) VALUES(4, 180, 3, 1222222224);
```

The result ordering by `timestamp DESC` should be the second record of table stars with `timestamp` 1222222224 then the third record of table posts with `timestamp` 1222222223 and following... Since the tables have got different fields from each other, the first row of the result should contain the columns of the table stars while the columns of table posts should be empty.

Comment: Just edit your question if you need to provide additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The columns of a UNION *must* be the same **name** and **datatype** on every row.  In fact, declare column aliases in the first UNION subquery, because it ignores any attempt to rename the column in subsequent subqueries.

If you need the columns from the two subqueries to be different, put in NULL as placeholders.  Here's an example, fetching the common columns id and timestamp, and then fetching one custom column from each of the subqueries.

```
(SELECT p.id, p.timestamp AS ts, p.fromid, NULL AS daynum  FROM posts)
UNION
(SELECT s.id, s.timestamp,       NULL,     s.daynum,       FROM stars)
ORDER BY ts DESC
```

Also put the subqueries in parentheses, so the last ORDER BY applies to the whole result of the UNION, not just to the last subquery.

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT one_id AS id, one_someinfo AS someinfo, one_ts AS ts
 UNION
 SELECT two_id AS id, two_someinfo AS someinfo, two_ts AS ts
 ORDER BY ts
```

Comment: thanks, i already tried with UNION but unfortunately the fields of the table are different from eachother. They only have the id and timestamp field in common. So that solution doesn't work for me

Comment: Could you post your CREATE TABLE codes and an example of desired result?

Comment: i posted the structure of the table in the reply above, hope it'll help. Thank you for responding, i'm new here

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT one_id AS id
       , one_someinfo AS one_someinfo
       , NULL         AS two_someinfo
       , one_ts AS ts
  FROM t_ONE
UNION ALL
  SELECT two_id 
       , NULL
       , two_someinfo
       , two_ts
  FROM t_TWO
ORDER BY ts
```